# How to check number of files of same extensions (e.g .txt) inside a folder in Adobe Air 2.0?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, filesystems

Is there any way to find total number of files of same types (e.g. ".txt" files) inside
a folder?

Comment: You will have to filter out the list as you see fit. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#getDirectoryListing%28%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, is the solution i found.

```
//Tested on AIR 2.0
import flash.filesystem.File;

//e.g. Say you want to target documents folder of your OS
var MyFolder:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("Temp");

var totNumOfFiles:Array = MyFolder.getDirectoryListing();
var numOfSameFileType:Array = [];

for (var i:uint = 0; i < totNumOfFiles.length; i++)
{
    if(totNumOfFiles[i].type == ".txt" )
    {
        numOfSameFileType.push(i);
    }else
    {
        trace("No text files.");
    }
}

trace("Total " + numOfSameFileType.length + " text files are available.");
```